# Is Nike Hindsight glasses only a concept or there are a real similar products?

Tags: glasses

I came across the following issue - ['Nike' Hindsight concept glasses increase peripheral vision](http://www.gizmag.com/nike-hindsight/12148/).

By the time of its publishing, these glasses were only a concept. My Question: is there a similar real working product in production?

Answer (score 7):

The Hindsight glasses include fresnel lenses that widen the peripheral field, at the cost of increased distortion. As stated in the article, this is a design concept, so there's no guarantee it will ever make it to market. And although it's a neat idea, it would take a lot of testing to determine whether the tradeoffs are worth it for enough people.

This isn't the only example of fresnel glasses being used in eyewear. [Peripheral prism glasses](http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2008/05/080512163833.htm) have been used in research for how to improve the vision of patients with hemianopia (blindness in half of the visual field), but although this is a related concept, it requires a completely different design.

In summary, no, fresnel lenses to extend peripheral vision are not readily available in cycling glasses.